# Can't parse wordpress feed with simple pie

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

i was trying to parse the rss feed of my wordpress blog, but it won't load, just shows me a white screen!
the strange thing is that it work with the feed of wordpress.org
what's wrong here???
tried already example.com/news/feed instead of domain.com/feed
addes also the php setting

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

it just don't work, help please

```
<?php

    // Make sure SimplePie is included. You may need to change this to match the location of autoloader.php
    // For 1.0-1.2:
    #require_once('../simplepie.inc');
    // For 1.3+:
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../php/autoloader.php');

    // We'll process this feed with all of the default options.
    $feed = new SimplePie();

    // Set the feed to process.
    $feed->set_feed_url('https://www.example.com/feed/');

    // Run SimplePie.
    $feed->init();

    // This makes sure that the content is sent to the browser as text/html and the UTF-8 character set (since we didn't change it).
    $feed->handle_content_type();

    // Let's begin our XHTML webpage code.  The DOCTYPE is supposed to be the very first thing, so we'll keep it on the same line as the closing-PHP tag.
    ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"


    <html xmlns="
    <head>
        <title>Sample SimplePie Page</title>




    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo $feed->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $feed->get_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php echo $feed->get_description(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php
        /*
        Here, we'll loop through all of the items in the feed, and $item represents the current item in the loop.
        */
        foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
        ?>

            <div class="item">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
                <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you are closing out your DOCTYPE :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML declaration was without a closing `"`.

```
<?php
    // Make sure SimplePie is included. You may need to change this to match the location of autoloader.php
    // For 1.0-1.2:
    #require_once('../simplepie.inc');
    // For 1.3+:
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../php/autoloader.php');

    // We'll process this feed with all of the default options.
    $feed = new SimplePie();

    // Set the feed to process.
    $feed->set_feed_url('https://www.example.com/feed/');

    // Run SimplePie.
    $feed->init();

    // This makes sure that the content is sent to the browser as text/html and the UTF-8 character set (since we didn't change it).
    $feed->handle_content_type();

    // Let's begin our XHTML webpage code.  The DOCTYPE is supposed to be the very first thing, so we'll keep it on the same line as the closing-PHP tag.
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample SimplePie Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo $feed->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $feed->get_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php echo $feed->get_description(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php
        /*
        Here, we'll loop through all of the items in the feed, and $item represents the current item in the loop.
        */
        foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
        ?>

            <div class="item">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
                <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```